# Vim change filetype of file with extension `.pl` to prolog instead of perl

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

The default filetype of a file with `.pl` extension is perl.
However I use prolog more often so every time I open a new file I have to set it manually by running vim command

`:set filetype=prolog`

I tried to automate it by inserting the the following line into `~/.vimrc`

`autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.pl   set syntax=prolog`

also tried inserting this line in `.vim/ftdetect/pl.vim` file in vain.

What should be done to set `.pl` files to prolog type instead of perl?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `set filetype` instead of `set syntax` in your vimrc?

Comment: Feeling stupid -_-  Thanks bro :) (y)

Answer (score 9):

Vim should detect this automatically, but you can override this by 
setting the variable g:filetype_pl in your .vimrc accordingly:

```
let g:filetype_pl="prolog"
```